# Extracting array element in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need little help regarding arrays in Matlab.

Let say I define an array `A=[2 3]`, Which means that my array has maximum 6 elements and I define another array with `B=[1 1]`, which means the element on 1st row and 1st column in array `A`.

My array `A` will always have numbers from 1 to the max limit of array like in current cas it's 2x3=6 so the max number will be 6 and the elements will be from 1-6. The problem is that I won't define these numbers in my array I will assume it.

Now I am working on making a formula that regurns 1, if my array `B` has numbers 1 and 1 and 1st row and 1st column of `A` has 1 , if `B` has numbers like `B=[2 3]`, the output will be 6 as the 2nd row and 3rd element number is 6.

Can anyone help me

Right Now I have crated this code

```
A=[2 3];
B=[1 1];
x=B(1);
y=B(2);

out=A(x,y);
```

But this code will work only if I have defined elements in my array. I don't want to define the numbers in my array and just want to assign the limit the the array `A`.

Comment: Are you trying to preallocate the size of the array? If so, try `A = zeros(2,3)`.

Comment: "I don't want to define the numbers in my array , I just want to assign the limit the array A" --> Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: @Luis Mendo: I mean that I am just defining the size of an Array A that it would contain max 2x3=6 elements in it, So Virtually it will have numbers from 1-6 , If I define A as [4 4] then it will have numbers from 1-16 (4x4=16) . This is just the max limit of an array and I will consider it as from 1 to the max limit of the array . and in 2nd array I am using the index to print the number at that particular row and column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as:

One liner, which I don't recommend due to two reasons: 1. Code should be easily readable. 2. `subsref` is usually used for overriding the operators `{}, (), .` and not for this type of task.

```
C=subsref(reshape(1:A(1)*A(2),A(1),A(2)),struct('type','()','subs',{{B(1),B(2)}}))
```

Or,

```
C=reshape(1:(A(1)*A(2)),A(1),A(2));
out1=C(B(1),B(2));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
 A(sub2ind(size(A), B(:,1), B(:,2)))
```

Example:

```
>> A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6];
>> B = [1 1; 3 2];
>> A(sub2ind(size(A), B(:,1), B(:,2)))
ans =
     1
     6
```

Comment: Thanks , I mean that I am just defining the size of an Array A that it would contain max 2x3=6 elements in it, So Virtually it will have numbers from 1-6 , If I define A as [4 4] then it will have numbers from 1-16 (4x4=16) . This is just the max limit of an array and I will consider it as from 1 to the max limit of the array . and in 2nd array I am using the index to print the number at that particular row and column

As you have defined numbers in ur array , I don't want to define numbers in an Array

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like the following:

```
out = A(2)*(B(1)-1) + B(2)
```

You could provide a clearer explanation for the problem though. (ofc, this will just fail if the elements of B are not within the range specified by A).